# I can't connect to Ingres with php 5.4

Tags: php, .net, xampp, wamp, ingres

I have windows xp with xampp installed and the problem is at moment to connect with ingres DB show me this error **Fatal error: Call to undefined function ingres_connect() ** I read about it and I tried to load the extension php_ingres.dll and edit my php.ini with the name of my ext. I have php 5.4 somenone has this extension php_ingres.dll if you need more information please let me know. I installed the client ingres too.

Comment: Did you reboot Apache after making the change to php.ini?

Comment: Yes, I reboot my apache to load the extension and show me this error "This aplicationhas failed to start because OIAPI.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix the problem."  and then appear another message "php startup : Unable  to load dynamic library c:\xampp\php\ext\php_ingress.dll - the specified module could not be found" i re check the file and it is in the path of the message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an error tipically, because you don't have installed PHP drivers Ingress and PHP.ini can't resolve it, please download PHP drivers and later add it extension=php_ingres.dl in PHP.INI of your xampp server. You can check if extension was loaded using: extension_loaded('php_ingres').

Ingres 10.1.0 Community edition: http://esd.ingres.com/product/Community_Projects/Ingres_Database/Windows_32-Bit/Ingres_10.1_Build_121/ingres-10.1.0-121-gpl-win-x86-NoDoc.zip/http

PHP drivers here: http://esd.ingres.com/product/drivers/PHP/Windows_32-Bit/PHP_Driver

Comment: Thanks. Let me try it and I'll back with comments